# Error! Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean java.util.ListIterator.hasNext()' on a null object reference-Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio-2.3

here is my code

```
ArrayList<Node> list = new ArrayList<>();
NodeComparer nodecomparer = new NodeComparer();
public int Push(Node start) {
    Collections.sort(list);
    int k = Collections.binarySearch((Node)start, nodecomparer);
    return k;
}
```

and i am calling it from another class

```
SortedCodeNodeList Open = new SortedCodeNodeList();
int x = Open.Push(Start);
```

i am converting this code from c# to java but i am facing a little problem here.

Comment: Provide few lines from top of StackTrace.

Comment: i am trying to convert the following code from c# (System.Collections Library) to java. Here is the method that was used in there.
    ArrayList.BinarySearch(Object, IComparer)
this code code of line compares the nodes and return -1,0,+ve Integer to determine the location in BInary Search